# How to share heroku remote tracking info with other developers on a team

Tags: git, heroku

I have set up multiple heroku instances for the same repository, as outlined [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments). As recommended, each heroku instance corresponds to a different remote (staging, production, etc.).  My challenge is that several members of our team will be deploying. However, the heroku remotes only exist in my local git after I've set them up with heroku. What is the best way for other team members' git clones of the repository to also be aware of the heroku remotes so they can also push to them for deployments?  We use a gitolite (similar to a private github) server for a central git repository and push and pull changes from that.

Comment: heroku_san seems to do what you're looking for
https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san

Comment: I didn't mention that this was a python/django app, but that looks like it would be a good solution for rails developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about they set up a git remote for each app?  eg.

```
git remote add production git@heroku.com:furious-robot-218.git
git remote add staging git@heroku.com:furious-wind-28.git
```

The `heroku create` you used to create those apps, creates the app on Heroku's side, but also created a git remote for you on your side.  For example, if you did this, you'd see your remotes:

```
git remote -v
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll just add a script to the repo that they can run to set those up. That way there won't be any typo issues, and we'll all be on the same page.